# Connecting to VPN with OpenVPN and obfsproxy

Tags: linux, obfsproxy, openvpn

I'm on Fedora 20 and having trouble connecting to my VPN using OpenVPN and obfsproxy. I can connect using the Windows client through VirtualBox (though only to certain servers, many of them restart continually) which i think is essentially just an interface for OpenVPN with obfsproxy. The Android OpenVPN port by Arne Schwabe also connects just fine using the same configuration file.

Now on my Linux box, i start up obfsproxy with:

```
> obfsproxy obfs2 socks 127.0.0.1:1050
```

... and then try to start up OpenVPN. It connects (or at least it says "Initialization Sequence Completed"), but after a minute it times out ("Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting" \ "SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting"):

```
> sudo openvpn --config IVPN-Singlehop-USA-SaltLakeCity-UT-OBFS.ovpn
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 OpenVPN 2.3.4 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [MH] [IPv6] built on Sep 19 2014
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, LZO 1.08
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 WARNING: file 'pass.txt' is group or others accessible
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 WARNING: file 'client1.key' is group or others accessible
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 WARNING: file 'ta.key' is group or others accessible
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:1050 [nonblock]
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:1050
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Fri Sep 19 14:06:37 2014 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:1050
Fri Sep 19 14:06:38 2014 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:1050, sid=280adaf7 b6f56f88
Fri Sep 19 14:06:38 2014 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Sep 19 14:06:40 2014 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=MT, ST=Malta, L=Malta, O=IVPN.net, CN=IVPN.net CA, emailAddress=support@ivpn.net
Fri Sep 19 14:06:40 2014 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Fri Sep 19 14:06:40 2014 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=MT, ST=Malta, L=Malta, O=IVPN.net, CN=gw3.us.ivpn.net, emailAddress=support@ivpn.net
Fri Sep 19 14:06:44 2014 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri Sep 19 14:06:44 2014 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 19 14:06:44 2014 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri Sep 19 14:06:44 2014 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Sep 19 14:06:44 2014 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 4096 bit RSA
Fri Sep 19 14:06:44 2014 [gw3.us.ivpn.net] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:1050
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 SENT CONTROL [gw3.us.ivpn.net]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 10.16.8.1,route 10.16.8.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.16.8.14 10.16.8.13'
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlp3s0 HWADDR=00:1b:b1:a8:a2:12
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 /usr/sbin/ifconfig tun0 10.16.8.14 pointopoint 10.16.8.13 mtu 1500
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 /usr/sbin/route add -net 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 /usr/sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.16.8.13
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 /usr/sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 10.16.8.13
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 /usr/sbin/route add -net 174.37.86.108 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 /usr/sbin/route add -net 10.16.8.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.16.8.13
Fri Sep 19 14:06:46 2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri Sep 19 14:07:46 2014 [gw3.us.ivpn.net] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Fri Sep 19 14:07:46 2014 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Fri Sep 19 14:07:46 2014 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Fri Sep 19 14:07:51 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Fri Sep 19 14:07:51 2014 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:1050 [nonblock]
Fri Sep 19 14:07:51 2014 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:1050
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 recv_socks_reply: TCP port read timeout expired: Operation now in progress (errno=115)
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 /usr/sbin/route del -net 10.16.8.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 /usr/sbin/route del -net 174.37.86.108 netmask 255.255.255.255
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 /usr/sbin/route del -net 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 /usr/sbin/route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 /usr/sbin/route del -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 /usr/sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
Fri Sep 19 14:07:56 2014 SIGTERM[soft,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

I've been working with this for about a week now and am at a loss what to do to get it to actually connect. I'm not sure if it's a firewall issue or what, but i'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?